# Update textbox value to database table using a condition in php

Tags: php, sql-server

[image: screenshot]

When I enter `0` in the **update** textbox and click on submit button the `Download_status` must change to `1` and vice versa. I am using SQL server 2008 and PHP.
The Text box value must be **reflected** in the database table **Download_status**.
Is this possible?

Output sample:

> Branch_code   -> AM   ,   AM    ,  AM
>
> Palmtec_id    ->AM06  ,  AM07  , AM08
>
> Download_status-> 0    ,   1  ,    1
>
> Query:
>
> select
>
> Branch_code,Palmtec_id,Download_status from tbl_download  where
>
> Branch_code='AM' and Palmtec_id='AM06'
>
> order by Branch_code,Palmtec_id

Comment: So just add condition in your submit button code to change Download_status based on update text box value. or you can use ajax for realtime changes.

Comment: i dont know how to add a condition...Can u hlp me?

Comment: Post your php code here

Comment: So upload necessary code .. like form and database table .. php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// REMEMBER TO SANITIZE THIS INPUT!
$palmtec_id = $_POST['palmtec_id'];
$update_status = $_POST['update_status'] ? 0 : 1;

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_download SET Download_status=$update_status WHERE Palmtec_id=$palmtec_id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

UPDATE for select query:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // REMEMBER TO SANITIZE THIS INPUT!
    $palmtec_id = $_POST['palmtec_id'];
    $update_status = $_POST['update_status'] ? 0 : 1;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_download WHERE Palmtec_id=$palmtec_id";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    if("1" == $row["Download_status"]){
    echo "0";
    }else{
    echo "1";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
    // OPTIONAL
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you want? To update the DB when update is submitted or to display the update after you query the DB?

Comment: First thing is to display the update after querying the DB..I tried your code the database gets updated wherein the front end side it gets blank after giving that query..Dont na where I went wrong

Comment: update  tbl_download set Download_status=1 where Branch_code='AM' and Palmtec_id='AM06'

Comment: when I click on update the DB value gets updated ...I just want to make it appear in the front end now..Can u help me?

Comment: Sure! Update and select must be two different queries, you can have both of them in the same script, and as many as you want. So after the update, you need to do a select query and from the result print the current value of Download_status. Remember, when you do an update, you erase the current value and replace it with the new one, so you dont have a history of the value, just the current one. Do you need code?

Comment: update tbl_download set Download_status='$up' where Branch_code='$branch' and Palmtec_id='$macid' 
 (select Branch_code,Palmtec_id,Download_status from tbl_download
     where Branch_code='$branch' and Palmtec_id='$macid')

Comment: I got it working perfectly after using this Query ... Thanks a lot @daniel for helping me out

Comment: I just need to display a pop up saying updated successfully after the value gets updated...How can i do that @daniel

Comment: Sure! The code provided for the update only changes the Download_status field